# Can you extrapolate the "email address" from a websites std. contact us form?

Tags: android

Trying to obtain the "path" that a websites contact form has.
Is there a way to "reverse engineer" the std. "contact us" form to find out the actualy email address that it goes to ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally not. The form will send it's data back to the web server, which may then send an email or do something else entirely like store it in a database or send it off to a CRM or ticketing system.

In days of yore people sometimes used an email address as the target of the form but I can't remember the last time I saw that.

Answer (score 0):

Not usually.

Unless the e-mail address is embedded in the HTML or JavaScript code that your web browser executes, you are not going to find it anywhere. You can search for something that looks like an e-mail address by viewing the source code sent down to your browser, but this is probably going to be a waste of time.

Contact forms usually submit their data back to a web server, and the web server processes that data and sends the e-mail from that point. This operation is communication between the server and other computers, where your computer is no longer involved.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way to have my app automaticlly email a specific company, but the website only has a contact me form, no email address.  Can I somehow use an autofill to complete the form....with no user interaction. ?

Comment: You might be able to send a specially crafted HTTP POST request to the same url that the form is posting to. You'll have to check out the source code of the form to find out what data to send. Maybe this article can help you along the way: http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/HTTPPost/

Comment: I guess I'm not clear as to your intent. Are you trying to write a web application that submits an e-mail, or are you a user trying to figure out where an e-mail is going when you submit a form? My answer assumes the latter. You might want to re-edit your question to make it more clear.